# Cast a value and set a property using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to set a property of an object dynamically. The method takes a parameter of type `object` and sets the property of the object using `PropertyInfo.SetValue()`.

```
public void SetValue(object value)
{
    var valueType = value.GetType();

    // Passes
    if (!_propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(valueType)) return;
    var valueType = value.GetType(); 

    // Tried but this doesn't help
    // var value = (dynamic) value;     

    // Fails   
    _propertyInfo.SetValue(value, Element, null);        
}
```

Pretty basic, as you can see. However, I keep getting a `TargetException` because `object has the wrong type`.

> Additional information: Object does not match target type.

[image: Exception]

I don't know if this refers to the value or the object whose property I want to set. Both definitely are of the expected types. However, value is passed in as `object` and `Element` is passed in as a base type of the `DeclaringType` of the property info.

Is that the cause for the problem? How can I workaround this limitation, if the concrete type of `Element` is unknown?

Comment: shouldn't you swap `value` and `Element` in `SetValue` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axt1ctd9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. You should swap `value` and `object` parameters:

```
_propertyInfo.SetValue(Element, value, null);
```

Comment: Also, if targeting .NET 4.5 (Visual Studio 2012) or later, you can leave out the last `null` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (!_propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(valueType)) return;
```

into

```
if (!_propertyInfo.DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(valueType)) return;
```

In the example

```
abstract class Vehicle
{
    public int NumberOfWheels { get; set; }
}
```

the `PropertyType` is `int` while the `DeclaringType` is `Vehicle`.

---

This answer assumed you really wanted `value` to be the target object. As others have realized, you probably meant `Element` to be the target. In that case your `IsAssignableFrom` was correct, you just needed to swap the arguments to `SetValue` (see Vlad's answer).

Comment: My intention was to set the value on element, but you noticed the error anyway. Thanks!